# Error by schedule ssis package in sql server 2008 agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

When I execute my SSIS Package manually it works just fine, But when I try to execute it from SQL agent i always get an error. In my case the SSIS is called from a certain path in the server. 
. The error is as follows:
[image]

Also when I See the Job Scrip I see the following under 
@command N'/FILE "N:\HRSSource\SSIS-Pakete IUT-NAV-MSSQL-2 .....

Maybe the error is comming from the N'FILE?

Comment: What account does the Job run under, does it have access to the N drive and the correct permissions? Is N a drive mapping, does it work if you use the full path instead?

Comment: Why have you completely changed your question? The answers given now no longer make sense. Please restore your original question, if my answer solved that question then except the answer, and then ask a new question for your OLEDB issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the mapped drive use the UNC path instead, something like \servername\filepath.

For the Job to access network folders I think you need to set up a proxy with a domain account credentials and that is configured to run jobs of type SQL Server Integration Services Packages.

Comment: Hi Dave: After using the full path now I have this error: "SSIS Error code DTS_E_OLEDB_NOPROVIDER_64BIT_ERROR" is not registered  ---> any idea why i got this error ?

Comment: What does your package do? Does the error message say which OLE DB provider failed? It looks like it's trying to connect to a data source using a 64bit driver that doesn't exist on your server. Have you tested the package on the server not using bids?

Comment: Its says the DB20LEDB is not registered. I am reading about this problem since 3 house and i tried almost everything. I made the project to run in 32 bit in both side SSIS Project and server. still the same error :(

Comment: In the SQL Agent Job on the Execution options tab did you select 'Use 32 bit runtime'?

Comment: Yes and nothing happened the same error, See Pic above, I posted the error.

Comment: The thing you are missing (and failing to clarify is: Is the SQL Agent on a different server to the computer you developed the package on? Answer that and we may be a step closer to helping

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message. It clearly states that the problem is that a package was not found on the path where the program searches for it. As a result, the error occurs and you see the error message. You should look at the location and see whether it exists, the user you are logged in with has the necessary rights for it and the package exists where it is searched for. If not, then according to your needs, change the necessary privileges or copy the missing package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but how come the Agent didnot find the package and in the same time I was able to select the package path from the general tab (while creating the agent job) and the agent found it?

Comment: Was the package at the location where the Agent searched for it?

Comment: yes after usuing full path, and the error now is DTS_E_OLEDB_NOPROVIDER_64BIT_ERROR"

Comment: You might have the wrong version. From the error I suppose you have a 64-bit OS and the package was implemented for 32 bits, this could lead to the incompatibility experienced.

Answer (score 0):

The job runs **on the server**, and I assume when you *set up* the job you didn't do it on the server, you did it on a remote client?

If you *did* set it up on the server, then most likely N is a mapped drive, which the SQL Agent service account is not aware of. So use a UNC path instead.

The SQL Agent service account (or proxy) also needs access to this UNC path